# why is my EcecuteSQLCommand statement returning -1

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have an SQL statement in my asp.net MVC controller which needs to get an int called siteUniqueID.

```
int siteUniqueID = AdminDatabase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
    ("Select SiteUniqueID from Settings where SiteID = " + id + "");
```

This statement brings in the id which is working and is giving the number required but is always settings siteUniqueID to -1.

Comment: Do you mean the statement returning -1? or the statement set the SiteUniqueID to -1? For that's totally different issue.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlQuery method allows you to return entities from the database. Where as ExecuteSqlCommand just runs the command and returns the status code from the DB.